# Where is the fetched branch stored after a successful git pull?

Tags: git, fetch, branch, pull

When I execute a `git pull` is the fetched branch stored anywhere in my local repository? If yes, how can I reference its contents? If it is not, is there a way to make `git pull` do so?

I understand that I can use `git fetch` and `git merge` to achieve this. However, for reasons not worth mentioning here it would be really helpful to us if we could achieve the same using `git pull`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword to reference the fetched commitid is FETCH_HEAD.

Answer (score -1):

`git pull` does a fetch. Literally. It invokes fetch. It does that, to fetch the history of the pulled tip(s). Its docs say so, they tell you this:

> In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.
>
> More precisely, `git pull` runs `git fetch` with the given parameters and calls `git merge` to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch. With `--rebase`, it runs `git rebase` instead of `git merge`.

and the *first two words* of [the `git pull` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) that aren't pure boilerplate are "Fetch from".

So it's not at clear what's left to ask about where to find what `git pull` fetched.